# How to change the size of Navigation Bar based on Device?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm using iOS 9 constraints to programmatically set the layout of my app. I understand to create a nav bar programmatically I do the following:

```
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: My_Height))
```

The thing is, I would like the height of the nav bar to change as the devices change to make it proportional using constraints. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to set the height constant to constraint programmatically making an outlet and calculate proportionally

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;

Comment: create an IBOutlet and calculate the proportional value base on device height

Comment: heightConstraint.constant = height * (device height/base height)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the screen size using this:

```
var screenWidth: CGFloat {
    if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(screenOrientation) {
        return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    } else {
        return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    }
}
var screenHeight: CGFloat {
    if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(screenOrientation) {
        return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    } else {
        return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    }
}
var screenOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
}
```

You can then customize the size of the navigation bar depending on the height or width of the screen.